Is it possible to know the exact number of seconds since the creation of the universe?
B"H
In Rambam hilchos kiddush hachodesh 6:8 he gives a "beginning time" to calculate the day of the week in any time afterwards that the moon will appear. He later says that we're not trying to get the number of days that have passed since their, but just the day of the week.

Similarly, if you know the time of the conjunction for a particular
year and you add its remainder - either the remainder of an ordinary
year or the remainder of a leap year - to the time of the conjunction,
you will determine the time of the conjunction of the following year.
This method [of calculation] may be followed year after year for
eternity.
The first conjunction from which we begin, the conjunction of the
first year of creation, was on Monday night, 5 hours and 204 units
after nightfall7 (in numerical terms, 2 - 5 - 204). This is the
starting point for these calculations.
ח וְכֵן כְּשֶׁיִּהְיֶה עִמְּךָ יָדוּעַ מוֹלַד שָׁנָה זוֹ וְתוֹסִיף
שְׁאֵרִיתָהּ עַל יְמֵי הַמּוֹלָד. אִם פְּשׁוּטָה הִיא שְׁאֵרִית
הַפְּשׁוּטָה וְאִם מְעֻבֶּרֶת הִיא שְׁאֵרִית הַמְעֻבֶּרֶת. יֵצֵא לְךָ
מוֹלַד שָׁנָה שֶׁלְּאַחֲרֶיהָ. וְכֵן שָׁנָה אַחַר שָׁנָה עַד סוֹף
הָעוֹלָם. וְהַמּוֹלָד הָרִאשׁוֹן שֶׁמִּמֶּנּוּ תַּתְחִיל הוּא מוֹלַד
שֶׁהָיָה בַּשָּׁנָה הָרִאשׁוֹנָה שֶׁל יְצִירָה. וְהוּא הָיָה בְּלֵיל
שֵׁנִי חָמֵשׁ שָׁעוֹת בַּלַּיְלָה וּמָאתַיִם וְאַרְבָּעָה חֲלָקִים.
סִימָן לָהֶם בהר''ד וּמִמֶּנּוּ הוּא תְּחִלַּת הַחֶשְׁבּוֹן:

Still, the fact that he gives an exact start time seems like it should be theoretically possible to calculate the exact number of seconds that have passed since the beginning of that calculation/creation of the world.
Am I mistaken? Or id it actually possible to do so?
If it is, the answer should provide the calculations to do so, ideally from kiddish hachodesh, and give the number of seconds since the beginning of day one in the answer.
Although I might be getting confused because there were certain years that the beis din would make months either 29 or 30 days based on the riyah that we don't know about. But still, it's possible that we still do know the total number of days in each year etc. But I can't figure out exactly how, or if.

The beit din decisions don't change anything about the moon, so they all average back out. Just count 5784 years in months, adding in 7 leap months per 19 years

@DoubleAA interesting. You mean 5784 "simple lunar" years, 350-something (forgot what), plus the extra for 7 years per   nineteen? Would the extra leap months added because of the sheep or roads etc that is mentioned earlier make a difference, since we may not know when they did that?

Note that molad tohu (2-5-204) is purely theoretical, nearly a year before the actual creation of the moon in Elul.

@Awtsmoos--עצמות The months don't matter. You're counting lunar cycles. Every cycle is 29/12/793
